# Revert ToggleButton IsChecked state after user taps it

Tags: c#, uwp

Let's say you want to have a UI which is equivalent to that of a VCR's or portable audio cassette player's playback controls. You could have a few states: playing, fast forward/rewind, stopped, etc. You could represent these states as toggle buttons, and you want to do this in an MVVM fashion, so you'll bind `IsChecked`. In my particular case, we've opted to bind `IsChecked` as `OneWay` and also bind the `Tapped` event to a method on the (view)model. The Tapped event handler is what does the actual work when the user requests a state change, i.e. action to perform.

This all works great until you try to immediately undo a requested action or state change. Using the cassette example, let's say I want to rewind or play, but there is no cassette in the player. The buttons need to remain visually in the stopped state, not the play/rewind state. We can't disable the buttons because we tell the user *why* that action cannot be performed as they try to perform it.

To accomplish that, I thought I could simply raise `PropertyChanged` and get the buttons to reevaluate their state. Doesn't work. Even if I notify after awaiting an async call to show a modal, it doesn't work. Implementing it as a retemplated `ItemsControl` using `SelectedItem` doesn't work any better. There doesn't appear to be a way to intercept the event and mark it as handled. I don't want to resort to some `Task.Delay` trickery. What other options do I have? I could implement separate button styles/states using a standard Button and throw out `ToggleButton`s altogether, but I'm curious if that has some sort of consequence for automated UI testing or accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `TappedEventHandler`then you can actually use `IsChecked` from sender and revert the state.

```
    private void ToggleButton_Tapped(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(NoCasette == true)
        (sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked = false;            
    }
```

Comment: In previous instances of this problem, I was binding directly to a viewmodel method. In this case, it's a reusable control with direct access to those UI elements, so... this is simple and it works. Makes me feel a little silly for asking.

Answer (score 0):

> This all works great until you try to immediately undo a requested action or state change.

From your description, your code might look like this:

```cs
public async Task Start()
{
    await DoSomething()
    IsChecked = true;
}
```

When the task is interrupted or quickly switched, the state of the button cannot be guaranteed to be changed.

My suggestion is to use `VisualStateManager` to separate the visual representation of the button from the logic code to ensure the immediate response of the button.

First create a `UserControl` named **VCRButtonGroups**

**VCRButtonGroups.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ToggleButton Content="Pause" x:Name="PauseButton" Tapped="PauseButton_Tapped"/>
        <ToggleButton Content="Start" x:Name="StartButton" Margin="15,0,0,0" Tapped="StartButton_Tapped"/>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pause">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="StartButton.IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Target="PauseButton.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Start">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="StartButton.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Target="PauseButton.IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**VCRButtonGroups.xaml.cs**

```cs
private void PauseButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Pause",false);
    // Do other
}

private void StartButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Start", false);
    // Do other
}
```

This is just an example with two buttons, you can add new button based on this code. The advantage of this is that you can preset a set of states and then enter different states according to different trigger conditions to ensure that the UI can be displayed correctly.

Best regards.